# Underfull \hbox (badness 1226) in paragraph at lines 103--112

Tags: badness

I am getting these messages and don't know why! so please let me know how to fix them.

```
Overfull \hbox (1.90002pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active

 output.bbl, line 103
Underfull \hbox (badness 1226) in paragraph at lines 103--112

 output.bbl, line 103
Underfull \hbox (badness 4217) in paragraph at lines 103--112

 output.bbl, line 153
Underfull \hbox (badness 3557) in paragraph at lines 153--156

 output.bbl, line 220
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 220--222
```

Comment: Do you have URLs in your bibliography items?

Comment: yes, some of my bibliographies do have URLs, should I have to do anything about them?

Comment: Well, typesetting URLs is usually a pain. Can you please make an example of a bib entry, together with a minimal document that produces the warning?

Comment: @MISC{K&J,
author        = {kJ magnetics},
year          = {2011},
title         = {The original KJ magnet calculator},
howpublished  ={\url{https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp}},
note